# How do I edit the JSON config for an operation within a pipeline in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline, and an operation in it to copy a table.

I wish to edit the JSON. I can View the JSON by clicking the { } button, but it doesn't let me edit it

> Cannot edit in read-only editor.

How can I edit it, or do I literally have to pull the repo edit and republish? Presumably it has the capability of editing because you can change the items using the UI, although with limited scope

Comment: **although with limited scope** -- Could you explain it? Can you change anything using UI? or is it limited?

Comment: The UI is a kind of drag & drop, with dropdowns and buttons within the UI that let you edit elements of ADF. However under the hood this is just manipulating a JSON file. But I can't seem to edit the JSON file directly, it has to be through the limited UI. It lets you view it, but gives that message saying you can't edit it. Unless I pull the repo to my local disk, at which point I can simply edit it in notepad. It's a bit of a pain to do this.

Comment: Check if the pipeline is locked by another user. If it is, you'll need to wait until the lock is released. If the pipeline is part of a published pipeline, you'll need to create a new pipeline or make changes to the pipeline in a different environment.